# Will using ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx make my Service weaker

Tags: delphi, ipc, firewall

I use Delphi. My Server application is a Windows Service application and contains Sockets and FTP components to communicate between different machines. I also have a UI with which I want to communicate using IPC (Windows message: WM_COPYDATA).

I have separated my applications because of Firewalls restricting regular applications using Sockets.

Question: Will using ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx cause my Service Application to be blocked by Windows Firewall or AntiVirus Firewall ?

Comment: To answer your question - no, they will not block you due to using `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()`.  However, do note that window messages cannot pass across session boundaries.  Services run in Session 0, users (and the UI apps they execute) run in Session 1+.  So you can't send `WM_COPYDATA` messages from your service to a UI, or vice versa. You will have to use a different IPC solution, such as pipes, sockets, COM, etc.  And FYI, a firewall will block a service using sockets just as easily as it would block a UI app using sockets.

Comment: I am currently reading / writing into a SQL Lite database. But I want to reduce the frequency of reads. All I want to do is give a indication to the other EXE to read only when needed. Will Shared Memory work across Sessions ? I would rather read from memory frequently as compared to HDD.

Comment: "*All I want to do is give a indication to the other EXE to read only when needed*" - you can used [named Event objects](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/event-objects) for that. "*Will Shared Memory work across Sessions ?*" - yes, but only if you use the [`Global` namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/termserv/kernel-object-namespaces), and your apps that share memory have the [`SeCreateGlobalPrivilege`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa375728) privilege, which is needed to create file mapping objects in the Global namespace.